# Unfortunately, "app" has Stopped in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to developing android. And I got after writing my code and running the debugger: "Unfortunately App has stopped"

my main.java:

```
package com.stream.streamvideo;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
public class main extends Activity implements     SurfaceHolder.Callback,MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private SurfaceHolder vidHolder;
private SurfaceView vidSurface;
String vidAddress = "https://archive.org/download/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    vidSurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfView);
    vidHolder = vidSurface.getHolder();
    vidHolder.addCallback(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
//setup
    try {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDisplay(vidHolder);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(vidAddress);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
//start playback
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

My activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <SurfaceView
         android:id="@+id/surfView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

i dont know where the problems are
Does anyone know where my problem is?

Comment: logcat will tell u the reason

Comment: you are missing "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);" from your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try to replace this code :**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    vidSurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfView);
    vidHolder = vidSurface.getHolder();
    vidHolder.addCallback(this);
}
```

**Note :** before you find any view from xml you have to call setContentView().

Comment: Glad to help you !!! can you please approve and upvote so it may be help to other to solve same problem thanks.

Comment: @user3823838 dont give only comment,please mark " √ " if answer is useful to you so other reader can understand solution worked or not